# Название процессора (brand string)

Tags: windows, winapi, cpu, julia

По мере освоения [Julia](https://julialang.org/) столкнулась с такой проблемой. Мне нужно получить название процессора (brand string), для этого хочу использовать `NtQuerySystemInformation` (класс `SystemProcessorBrandString`), но как выделить под возвращаемые данные буфер? В смысле:

```
buff = ? # собственно, буфер
ntstatus = ccall((:NtQuerySystemInformation, "ntdll.dll"), stdcall, Int32,
             (UInt32, ?, UInt32, Ref{UInt32}), 105, buf, 0, requiredBytes)
```

Понимаю, что возвращаемый тип - `UInt8`, но как сделать корректное объявление буфера, а после еще и изменить, ведь при `ntstatus` равному `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH` в *requiredBytes* будет истинный размер буфера?

Comment: Может куда проще использовать ```Sys.cpu_info()```? Например: ```println(strip(split(repr(Sys.cpu_info()[1]), ':')[1]))``` - по идее не должно зависеть от платформы.

Comment: Действительно, так короче, но вопрос именно о WinAPI по причине того, чтобы понять механизм работы вызова функций из библиотек, принцип работы с буферами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# первый вызов NtQuerySystemInformation
buf, req = zeros(UInt8, 0), Ref{UInt32}(0)
nts = ccall((:NtQuerySystemInformation, "ntdll.dll"),
   stdcall, Int32,
   (UInt32, Ptr{UInt8}, UInt32, Ref{UInt32}),
   105, buf, 0, req
)

# равен ли NTSTATUS значению STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH
if reinterpret(Int32, 0xC0000004) != nts
   # выводим какую-либо полезную информацию и выходим
end

# изменяем размер буфера
resize!(buf, req[])

# второй вызов NtQuerySystemInformation
...

# проверяем NTSTATUS равен ли STATUS_SUCCESS
if 0 != nts
   # снова "разбор полетов"
end

# собственно brand string
println(strip(string(buf[1:req[] - 2])))
```